# Do i need to Issue ListItem.Update(), when i am executing these commands ( ListItem.ResetRoleInheritance() + ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add() )

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver

I am working on a remote event receiver inside SharePoint online custom list. now inside the RER i am getting the item been updated, then reset its role inheritance + add users to the item permission, as follow:-

```
projectItem.ResetRoleInheritance();
projectItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
projectItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oUser, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { readerDef });
FieldUserValue[] approvers = projectItem["Approvers"] as FieldUserValue[];
                    foreach (FieldUserValue user in approvers)
                            {
                              User oUser2 = context.Web.EnsureUser(user.LookupValue);
                              context.Load(oUser2);
                              context.ExecuteQuery();
                              projectItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oUser2, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { contributeDef });

                             }
```

now i thought to get the `ListItem.ResetRoleInheritance() + ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add()` working i need to execute `ListItem.Update()` at the end.. but based on my test the `ListItem.ResetRoleInheritance() + ListItem.RoleAssignments.Add()` will be applied without having to execute `ListItem.Update()`.. so is my assumption correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add `ListItem.Update()` when use reset listItem permission.

Official document about `ListItem.Update()` for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee536748(v=office.15)

Comment: ok thanks for the info